# Import large amount of data into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I have to import over 100000 entries into many tables.

I have only the queries for doing this but i can run only 1000 at a time.

Do you have any idea of how can I do this faster ?

Thank you

Comment: Check out [`BULK INSERT` (T-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) or [`SqlBulkCopy` (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) as ways to import masses of data

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know about this solution. The ideea is that I have only the quieries, it will take me a while to transform those queries into a Bulk Insert. Is there a config option to increase the number from 1000 to 100000?